# Updating a SQLite database from a web service

Tags: android, sqlite, rest, crud

I have an android studio app with a sqllite database, when the user accesses the app, I would like to hit a restful webservice that will send JSON or similar and update/replace the data in the tables, does anyone have any advice/good tutorials on this?

Haven't had to do this before in Android studio, primarily react js developer where it is much simpler and straight forward in my experience.

just hoping for a few good tutorials on the subject and any tips to avoid common pitfalls.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For easy object-oriented update, you need to use ORM. For example, Realm or for sqllite - SugarORM: https://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html